# What feature in Haskell cannot be emulated with Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell

Currently I am learning Scala and Haskell.

I was wondering if Haskell is more powerfull in some way than Scala (+ ScalaZ)? 
I know for example that Haskell's Algebraic Data Types, TypeClasses, currying, laziness etc. can be implemented in Scala just fine.

Is there some Haskell program that cannot be easily mapped to Scala? If yes, what is the missing feature in Scala that prevents this mapping?

My intuition is that Scala is at least as powerful as Haskell, I am just not sure if this intuition is correct. Can someone confirm this ?

EDIT:
I see the point of Abrahamson's. The definition of emulation is indeed crucial. I would define emulation from a practical point of view, given a programmer who knows both Haskell and Scala can transform a 100 line Haskell code into an equivalent Scala codes say in 1-2 hours. Now is the question, what is equivalent? That means, transforming the logical constructs that are in the Haskell code into equivalent logical constructs in Scala, for example Type Classes in Haskell transformed into equivalent constructs implemented with implicits.

EDIT 2: 
Response to Travis' comment: for simplicity lets only consider vanilla Haskell.

EDIT 3:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815503/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-of-scala-and-haskell-type-systems?rq=1) question is similar.

Comment: Other than an optimizing compiler and everything being lazy by default without needing to explicitly declare it as such?

Comment: And type inference that doesn't let you down just when you need it most?

Comment: This is a little poorly defined due to the usual: you can just write a Haskell interpreter in Scala and get whatever functionality you like. Unless "emulation" gets a stricter definition, I doubt this question will have a meaningful answer.

Comment: You might also clarify whether you mean Haskell proper or Haskell plus all the GHC extensions—e.g. kind polymorphism is a pretty neat thing Scala doesn't have.

Comment: "My intuition is that Scala is at least as powerful as Haskell". Depends on what kind of power you are talking about. Too subjective. My intuition is that Haskell is way more powerful than Scala.

Comment: Scala is impure and you can't fix that. Besides other benefits, due to purity, Haskell's type system is able to provide safety and guarantees in the areas, which Scala doesn't even approach. E.g., with monads you can provide an intentionally limited set of operations for a context thus securing it from undesired side-effects (check out STM). In Scala, on the other hand, you can launch rockets from any point of your program without having any notion about it in types. The bugs such things introduce can be very hard to track, since they require restoring the whole program to a specific state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Scala has type inference, it is weaker than Haskell's since Haskell uses a (extension of a) [Hindley-Milner type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) which allows for particularly powerful inference.  Scala's type system allows for a more expansive notion of types (e.g. it's object-oriented also) which means that the type inference algorithm Haskell uses doesn't work.  (Also, as a practical matter, Scala's type inference is weaker than it could be in order to make it easier on the compiler and compiler-writers.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! This is a feature why my intuition was not correct, so Haskell **is** more powerful in some respect. Good to keep this in mind !

Comment: That last sentence is a bit of a mischaracterization of the issues involved. The Scala Language Designers *do* know how to make Type Inference more powerful, and the compiler writers *do* know how to implement it. What they *don't* know is how to provide good error messages. And the Scala community values good error messages so highly that they are even okay with giving up expressive power in the language if that particular feature interferes with good error messages. In Haskell, for example, you can run into the situation that a type error gets reported far away from the actual problem, …

Comment: … because even though the type inferencer takes a wrong turn in some part of the program, that doesn't actually lead to a contradiction until way further down the line in some far away almost unrelated part of the program. Even in Haskell, it's good practice to provide type annotations at module boundaries, but in Scala, every method is a module!